# How to narrow an XPath evaluation to a single node instead of a whole document in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

**XML stream**

```
<l>
    <i>
        <a>AAA</a>
        <b>BBB</b>
        <c>CCC</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        <a>AAA2</a>
        <b>BBB2</b>
        <c>CCC2</c>
    </i>
    <i>
        ...
    </i>
</l>
```

I want to output the following text with some Java code:

```
> CCC
> CCC2
...
```

Here is the code I wrote to produce the expected result:

**Java code**

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = docBuilder.parse("file:///C:/path/to/my/xml/stream.xml");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//i");

NodeList listOfiNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for(int i=0;i<listOfiNodes.getLength();i++) {
    XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("//c");
    System.out.println("> " + ((Node) expr2.evaluate(listOfiNodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent());   
}
```

`expr2` keeps on returning the first `c` node. So I get this output:

```
> CCC
> CCC
...
```

The evaluation performed by `expr2` doesn't seem to "stay" on the node passed to `evaluate()` method. Why?

**NOTA:** I don't want to get the `c` nodes directly with the xpath `//i/c` (or `/l/i/c`).

**Java 6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//c` selects all matching nodes in the whole document. Use `c` instead and you will receive this output:

```
> CCC
> CCC2
```

Note that you will get an NPE if a Node `i` does not contain a `c` in the line where you print the results. The following code should be working as expected:

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document d = docBuilder.parse("stream.xml");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//i");

NodeList listOfiNodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < listOfiNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("c");
    Node item = listOfiNodes.item(i);
    Node node = (Node) expr2.evaluate(item, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if (null != node) {
        System.out.println("> " + node.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `//` doesn't refer to the node I pass to the `evaluate()` method?

Comment: Because you are operating on the whole document - otherwise it would not be possible to use something like `ancestor`, `preceding`, `following`, `../` etc. in your XPath. In the example above `item` refers to the `current item` (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-current).

Answer (score 1):

Change `"//c"` with `".//c"`

```
XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile(".//c");
```

It will start the search anywhere *from* the current node instead of the whole document.

```
    XPathExpression expr2 = (XPathExpression) xpath.compile(".//c");
    for(int i=0;i<listOfiNodes.getLength();i++) {
        System.out.println("> " + ((Node) expr2.evaluate(listOfiNodes.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE)).getTextContent());   
    }
```

Output:

> CCC
>   CCC2

Comment: Why `//` doesn't refer to the node I pass to the `evaluate()` method?

Comment: `.//c` would only be necessary if there are further nodes `c` (`descendant`) below the first `c` - which is not the case in the example XML.